# No support for Xamarin.Firebase.Auth lower than MonoAndroid 7.0?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Xamarin.Firebase.Auth package from the nuget package manager and the dependencies says that it requires MonoAndroid 7.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/

Does that mean we can't use Firebase modules with Xamarin.Android on devices running lower than 7.0 when Firebase itself supports upto Ice Cream Sandwich.

Why is that so ?

Am I getting it wrong ?

Is there any way to use Firebase on Xamarin.Android lower than 7.0 ?

Comment: I have seen you asked the [same question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98599/no-support-for-xamarin-firebase-auth-lower-than-monoandroid-7-0) and accepted an answer, could you please post the answer so that someone else who have encounter the problem can see the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I asked on the Xamarin Forums too and got an answer [see here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98599/no-support-for-xamarin-firebase-auth-lower-than-monoandroid-7-0) .